# Difference between test app and test core library?

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I begun use template studio for WPF. When I create progect template ask me which module use for testing. So my question is: which difference between test app and test core library(look screenshot)?

[image: screenshot]

I expecting small explanation. What reason for test app and test core library? What need know about it?

Comment: This is no different from any app and any library project. A library produces a non-executable DLL that can be referenced in other projects.

Comment: Could you please give me advice. I never wrote unit-tests so what shoud use for project: test app or library?

Comment: A library is a resource that can be used by multiple apps. You can only do tests in apps.

Comment: The description is very clear: Each of them will create a test project. The first three will create it for the app and the other three for any library. To really understand what is going on and what and why to use it you first had to get in touch with testing in common and what is unit testing and what it is not.

Comment: You can even add tests to any other library/application in your solution, just reference a testing framework on your own (e.g. reference `MSTest.TestFramework` and `MSTest.TestAdapter` anywhere and you can write tests against the mstest framework)